# KendoUI 2013.3.1324: timezoneoffset and negative milliseconds value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, timezone-offset

I have updated my project to version 2013.3.1324 from 2013.3.1119 (with ASP.NET MVC wrappers)
And I saw the following after update: [image: grid invalid date error]
DateTime is passed to the client as

```
"/Date(-498283200000)/"
```

if less than 1970 year and

```
"/Date(498283200000)/"
```

if more that 1970 year

I have found a strange code in the **kendo.all.js** file

```
dateRegExp = /^\/Date\((.*?)\)\/$/,
tzOffsetRegExp = /[+-]{1}\d+/,

...

if (value && value.indexOf("/D") === 0) {
    date = dateRegExp.exec(value);
    if (date) {
        date = date[1];

        tzoffset = tzOffsetRegExp.exec(date);
        date = parseInt(date, 10);

        if (tzoffset) {
            date -= (parseInt(tzoffset[0], 10) * kendo.date.MS_PER_MINUTE);
        }

        return new Date(date);
    }
}
```

Debug info:
Initial value:
[image: initial value]

Parsed date value:
[image: date value]

Parsed tzo value:
[image: Parsed tz value]

And finally, result date value:
[image: result date value]

Actually I don't need time, only Date. Model property type is regular DateTime.
Also I can't find any issues with this release on the Kendo site.

What I'm doing wrong and what I need to do? (changing Kendo source is not an option I think...)

Example:

[image: console]

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/vebed/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed in the Internal build 2013.3.1408

New code is:

```
if (value && value.indexOf("/D") === 0) {
    date = dateRegExp.exec(value);
    if (date) {
        tzoffset = date = date[1];

        date = parseInt(date, 10);

        tzoffset = tzoffset.substring(1).split(signRegExp)[1];

        if (tzoffset) {
            date -= (parseInt(tzoffset, 10) * kendo.date.MS_PER_MINUTE);
        }

        return new Date(date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
alert(kendo.parseDate("/Date(-498283200000)/"))
```

shows

```
Thu Mar 18 1954 22:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)
```

with the latest official version of Kendo UI.

Make sure you are not using an older version.

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/vebed/1/edit

Comment: Sorry, but 2013.3.1119 is not a latest version. Latest version is 2013.3.1324 (as I have mentioned in the header). And here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/vebed/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: There may be a bug in 2013.3.1324. Try using an internal build. The latest one is 2013.3.1408.

Comment: Thank you Atanas, it's fixed in the internal build 1408.